# Diary of a hairdresser

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

Today I went to cut my hair, and the hairdresser told me a weird story.

> Yesterday, I had a group of people come to cut their hair. Together, they embodied the one type of hair I hate.
> A celebrity came in first, and brightly asked me to trim a bit past the middle.
> A player came in next, and pretendedly asked me for a number one.
> A glutton grunted at me to ask me to cut off a bit at the front.
> Finally, a fellow worker stylishly asked me to cut off everything but the ends.

## Can you work out what type of hair she doesn't like?

---

This story is based on a fictional event and taken from there...

Part of an upcoming <kbd>[metapuzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metapuzzles)</kbd>

Comment: Perhaps 'Theatrically' or 'dramatically' would have been better than 'pretendedly', but apart from that, great puzzle!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

She hates

> **STRAIGHT** hair.

---

A celebrity came in first, and brightly asked me to trim a bit past the middle.

> **ST**A**R** (clued by celebrity/brightly)

A player came in next, and pretendedly asked me for a number one.

> **A**CTOR (clued by player/pretendedly)

A glutton grunted at me to ask me to cut off a bit at the front.

> P**IG** (clued by glutton/grunted)

Finally, a fellow worker stylishly asked me to cut off everything but the ends.

> **H**AIRSTYLIS**T** (clued by fellow worker/stylishly)

Comment: Oh, you even got the ends!

Comment: Aaah, I was so close! Nice work

Comment: Great job! For Australasian, Oceanic and West American viewers, I'll accept in 8-14 hours - ping me on this comment if I forget.  Hope you liked the puzzle!